# How can you add an additional static IP to a DHCP configured interface with network-manager?

Tags: network-manager, 20.04

Under IPv6 it's much more common to have multiple IP addresses for the same interface.  This is most obvious with each interface having a [link-local address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address#IPv6) as well as it's [global unicast address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#General_allocation).

I have a network that is primarily configured using the DHCP(4/6) server on a home router.  However I want to add a [ULA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_local_address) to a number of devices as well as some associated static routes.  I want to add these addresses to the same interfaces as those already configured with DHCP.  My home router has no options to configure ULAs and certainly no option to add static routes.  I really don't want to setup and maintain an entirely new DHCP server for the sake of one laptop (*discussed below*).

I've found this is trivial [when configuring with netplan](https://askubuntu.com/a/1031449/39039), so my servers are easy to configure.  However I'm having trouble with my laptop (Ubuntu 20.04) which is configured with the network-manager through the GUI.  Here I seem to be limited to *either* selecting "Automatic" meaning DHCP, *or* entering static IPs.  There doesn't seem to be an option to do both.

Is there a way I can get into the configuration of network-manager such that I can configure it to add a static IP address to a DHCP configured interface profile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved with the network manager CLI. Eg:

```bsh
nmcli connection modify "$PROFILE_NAME" +ipv6.addresses fc00:b:c:0::5/64 +ipv6.routes 'fc00:b:c:1::/64 fc00:b:c:0::1'
```

Once the profile has been modified reactivate the profile with:

```bsh
nmcli connection up "$PROFILE_NAME"
```

Check the result with `ip -6 addr` and `ip -6 route`.

Comment: There is a typo here: "+ipv6.addressed" -> "+ipv6.addresses".