# My networkd netcfg does not connect to the internet

Tags: networking, server, 20.04, internet, ethernet

The company I work for builds server boxes for robot equipment. The robots communicate with the ubuntu server through ethernet connections and demand that the server has a static IP address. The robot and server are specifically connected through an ethernet switch which is also connected to the system's internet source. The struggle is, we cannot guarantee that the robot subnet and the router subnet overlap. To resolve this issue, we'd like to set up a single ethernet connection with two virtual IP addresses: one should be static for the robot's sake and the other should use DHCP and connect to the internet.

I found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031278/does-netplan-support-dhcp-and-static-addresses-on-one-interface) on stack exchange but it only half works.

Here's my cfg:

```
# /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp6: no
      addresses:
        - 192.168.1.51/24
```

When I run `sudo netplan try` and `ip address show eno1` in a new terminal, I see:

```
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c8:5a:cf:b2:f9:89 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp2s0
    inet 192.168.1.51/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eno1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.3.98/24 brd 192.168.3.255 scope global dynamic eno1
       valid_lft 86397sec preferred_lft 86397sec
    inet6 fe80::e6f:6cd2:29bc:f8be/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

This seems to be right and sure enough, the server is able to connect to the robot. Furthermore, we are even able to ping the router. However, it fails to actually connect to the internet. On the other hand, when I use standard DHCP from the xdg connection UI, I get the same IP address and I am able to get a connection.

My question then is, what am I doing wrong? How can I fix this? And is there a better way?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Your netplan file requests both an address by DHCP and a static address; obviously a conflict. I suggest that you check here:

```
cat /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/static.yaml
```

There you will find the template for setting a static IP address in Netplan. Amend your file accordingly and do:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

You should be all set.

Comment: Hint: You are missing DNS nameservers.

Comment: I appreciate your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that the original solution does in fact work. I bought a networking textbook that praised some software called cockpit so I downloaded it and was able to get things working quite fast. It turned out that something was adding a DNS server address of `0.0.0.0` to the network config (maybe a previously built config or something?) and I merely deleted the gateway from the cockpit UI and it worked like clockwork. The static DNS address probably was overriding the DHCP address and preventing the server from accessing the web. This also worked on two other servers so hopefully, I can rest knowing that this solution is robust.

For anyone combing the web for networking solutions, I highly highly recommend [cockpit](https://linuxways.net/ubuntu/how-to-install-cockpit-on-ubuntu-20-04/). It is fantastic for debugging servers.